# Flutter iOS App not launching after removing USB

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, dart

So i'm testing a flutter app that builds and installs successfully on an iOS simulator as well as a physical devices. However, when building and installing the app with xcode via the USB, it successfully installs and launches but when the USB is disconnected from my mac and i try to run the already installed device on the iPhone, it shows only the launch / splash screen and fades and closes.

Is there something i'm doing wrong that causes this to happen? As the app works fine when connected with the USB and it's being run.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the build is in debug mode - it won't open.

if you want to open application after disconnecting, try profile / release mode

```
flutter run --profile
```

or

```
flutter run --release
```

Answer (score 4):

In iOS, debug build doesn't work without USB. To use the app without USB trying making a release build using **flutter run --release**