# Splash screen not visible after removing USB from physical device Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter_native_splash package to display splash screen. This works fine when running the app on physical device but after disconnecting USB, I can only see white blank screen (no splash screen).

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316448/flutter-ios-app-not-launching-after-removing-usb) which suggest to run app in profiler or release mode. This also made no difference still I am not able to see the splash screen after disconnecting. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: is this behavior happens while debugging your app, or on release ?

Comment: While running the app in debug mode I am able to see the splash screen, but when I open the app after disconnecting USB there is no splash screen it directly shows the home screen of app. Then I checked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72316448/flutter-ios-app-not-launching-after-removing-usb) which suggested to run app in release mode by flutter run --release but again after disconnecting USB not able to see splash screen.

Comment: try to uninstall the debug installed apps on phone, then run in release mode

Comment: glad to help, can I add a proper answer so anyone getting into this trouble fix it ?

Comment: sure... I will mark that as accepted you can add it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue results when you frequently install multiple debug/release APKs on the device so they conflict with each other resulting in behaviors like returning to the previous debug version app when you disconnect the USB.

And you can avoid it, but uninstalling the debug version once you're done with it, then install the new release APK, And it should work fine.